# How to get div contents next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my div contents to be next to each other but they are being displayed under each other.

This div is aligned right and is part of the navigation bar div. I tried using float left for text but no improvements were made.

```
    <div align="right" class="log-in-checkout" id="left-nav">
                  <span class="login">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"><span class="hidden-xs text-uppercase">Sign-in</span></a> or <a href="customer-register.html"><span class="hidden-xs text-uppercase">Register</span></a>

                   </span>
                       <span class="checkout">
                           <a class="btn btn-shopping-cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i></a>
                       </span>
    </div>
```

Result:

> SIGN-IN 
>  or 
>  REGISTER 
>  Check-out icon

Whereas I want:

> SIGN-IN or REGISTER checkout icon

Comment: You need to provide CSS for the classes you used, they are what is causing the problem. Otherwise we will need to close the question since it cannot be reproduced in the same way.

Comment: What is up with all the spans? You can style the A tags how you want them. You a tags will align how you want them by default.

Comment: @Jørgen removed all spans and included the class and added hidden-xs text-uppercase classes in div and works well. Thanks!

Comment: @cgeekmt glad to hear! Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some other CSS you have in your code is affecting your styles. Putting in just your html renders as you expect it to render

```html
<div align="right" class="log-in-checkout" id="left-nav">
  <span class="login">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">
      <span class="hidden-xs text-uppercase">Sign-in</span>
    </a>
    or 
    <a href="customer-register.html">
      <span class="hidden-xs text-uppercase">Register</span>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="checkout">
    <a class="btn btn-shopping-cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i></a>
   </span>
</div>
```

It all depends on what styles are affecting it, but putting `display: inline-block` on the spans may fix things for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
div {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for float to work the div has to have `position: relative` attribute or `position: static`. Also only DIVs that have these set are affected by the flow of document.

If you put all your divs which you want to be ordered towards right/left side with these properties:

```
position:relative;
float: right;
```

they should automatically fit in.